# Can't deploy to app engine standard with gcloud components 272.0.0

Tags: google-app-engine

I haven't changed any of my yaml files for weeks.  Doesn't matter if I'm trying to push my go services or python.  Has anyone seen this error?  Note: It doesn't instil confidence that my production apps are being deployed with something called "experiments.yaml".

```
gcloud app deploy myApp.yaml -v v0-11-09 --project=myProject

ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Failed to parse YAML from [gs://runtime-builders/experiments.yaml]: mapping values are not allowed here
  in "<file>", line 2, column 14
make: *** [deploy] Error 1
```

Update:  This only occurs with the newest version of gcloud components (272.0.0)

I just reverted to the previous version (271.0.0) and all is well again.  Is there a way to report this as a bug to Google?  I'm not currently paying for support but would like to help the Google team if I was allowed to.

Comment: I encountered the same problem, and I also solved it by reverting to the previous version of the Google Cloud SDK.

Comment: Anyone using the cloud SDK from a docker container should revert to an older version using the direct tags: https://hub.docker.com/r/google/cloud-sdk/tags

Comment: As of 1.55PM(PDT), it seems to be fixed on the latest version. You can update to the latest again!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Having the same issue here.
As of now, the only way is to revert to an older version.

```
gcloud components update --version=271.0.0
```

As of 1.55PM(PDT), it seems to be fixed on the latest version. You can update to the latest again!

Comment: I downgraded my gcloud components per the above.  But my java/maven deploy is still failing with: INFO: submitting command: /Users/user/Library/Application Support/google-cloud-tools-java/managed-cloud-sdk/LATEST/google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud app deploy --project projectid
12:32:31.031 [INFO] GCLOUD: ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Failed to parse YAML from [gs://runtime-builders/experiments.yaml]: mapping values are not allowed here
12:32:31.031 [INFO] GCLOUD:   in "<file>", line 2, column 14

Comment: Try deleting your temp and target folder for the build of your project.

Comment: having this issue too but trying to deploy a react app. how do you delete the temp and target folder?

Comment: On windows the temp folder is accessible with %temp%, i'm not sure what is cached for your react application.
Worst case, doing a fresh install of the gcloud with an older version should fix it.

Comment: Apparently if are using maven, you have to downgrade the maven plugin version too.

Comment: As of 1.55PM(PDT), it seems to be fixed on the latest version. You can update to the latest again!